# Cucumber step doesn't recognize String

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd

My feature files in my cucumber project always worked until now.
It seems like the Strings I pass, aren't recognized anymore?

I used to do this:

```js
 @When("I set the local storage vars {string}, {string}, {string}")
```

But now it doesn't recognize all the steps I pass Strings in anymore.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? did you upgrade your cucumber version recently?

Comment: You might need to update IntelliJ / Cucumber plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the new version of cucumber(5.0.0). If you are using *IntelliJ*, just update the plugins and the IntelliJ itself.
From cucumber version 4.x.x you can use the below format to pass any kind of data types from your feature file and use it in whichever data type required. Below is the sample.

*Feature File:*

`When I set the local storage vars a, b, c`

*Step Definition File:*

`@When("I set the local storage vars (.*), (.*), (.*)")
    public void iSetTheLocalStorageVars(String a, String b, String c) {
    }`